# jquery: spaces is added instead of %20

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, space

I have a url (school.php/region%20division). When I click the anchor tag, it should open a page that will have the url school.php/region%20division. As of the moment, the page opens with the url school.php/region division. This contains a whitespace instead of %20. What should I do to keep the %20? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
var url=escape("school.php/"+region+' '+division); //school.php/region%20/division
$("a.searchLink").html("<a href="+url+">Click Here</a>");
```

Comment: That's probably just browser displaying the URL nicely. Check server's access log.

Comment: As @mishik said, that's just the browser showing the URL correctly. Ideally you shouldn't have spaces in a URL anyway.

Comment: You might generate invalid HTML. Better put quotes around the `href` value.

Comment: FYI [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.escape) has been superseded by [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) and [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).